# How to use Python expression only as hybrid property in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL Alchemy mapping:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'employee'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  first_name = Column(String)
  last_name = Column(String)

  @hybrid_property
  def me(self):
    return 'Yes!' if self.first_name == 'ritratt' else 'Nope...'
```

Now I simply want to do a query like so:
`session.query(Employee.me).all()`

But it does not work because SQL Alchemy expects a column or expression instead of a `str`. The solution is to use `hybrid_expression` but I do not want to use expressions. I want my mapping to only use hybrid property.

How can I write a mapping with a `hybrid_property` that returns a `str` and work with `query()`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky way around it. I use Python to derive the value and then wrap it either in `cast` or `concat`:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, String

...

@hybrid_property
  def me(self):
    value = 'Yes!' if self.first_name == 'ritratt' else 'Nope...'
    return cast(value, String) # or return concat('', value)
```

This still seems a bit hacky. Wondering if a better way exists

Comment: cast play good in this condition indeed !  another question is: can we use self.first_name to map a value ?  So we can return sth like dict[self.first_name]

Comment: It seems self.first_name is not able to compare with string "ritratt"